# How to prevent the rendering of unseen triangle in Unity3D?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rendering

In Unity3D the logic dictates that objects are not to be rendered unless in the field of view. This is obviously the way to go for optimization purposes. However, it still renders meshes that can not be seen by a player due to being occluded. I would like to solve this and was wondering if there was already a method to do so or if I had to do it myself.

Here's a picture to help illustrate my point.[image]

So far my only real ideas are using the culling, but that still would be in a range not necessarily visible.

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera-layerCullDistances.html

**I guess essentially what I need to know is how to do occlusion culling after a scene starts because the scene is generated, it's not premade.**

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who's interested, I asked the unity community

> Answer by Bunny83 · 4 hours ago
>
> No, that's not possible. At least not with the occlusion culling
>   system that Unity uses. The calculation which parts are visible from
>   which points is quite complicated and has to be precomputed in the
>   editor. So it won't work for procedurally generated levels.
>
> You have to roll your own solution if you need something like that.
>   Just a few weeks (or month?) ago i implemented a VisPortals solution
>   similar to those used by Doom3 (basically how most ID Tech engines
>   work). It's more a prove of concept than a ready-to-use solution.
>
> Usually i upload a webplayer demo onto my dropbox, however i just
>   realised that Dropbox finally prevented to directly view HTML pages
>   off my public folder. They now force a download of the page which
>   breaks everything. So if you want to try it, you have to download the
>   project.
>
> Of course vis portals doesn't work in all situations. They are perfect
>   for closed environments which can be split nicely into seperate areas.
>   Of course this splitting into areas and the creation of the visportals
>   currently is done by hand. So you would need to automate this
>   yourself.
>
> Be careful with static batching, it might break the system as each
>   area has to be seperate so it can be enabled / disabled seperately.